# Slow password history validation using BCrypt

Tags: bcrypt, password-encryption

We're using bcrypt to hash the users' passwords, and we store a list of the last 10 hashes to make sure they don't use the same password as the last 10 when they create a new one.

One issue we're running into is that checking the password history is a very slow process. The algorithm goes something like this:

```
// The user's entered password on the password change page
String rawPassword = ...

// For demonstration purposes, the password has passed all other validation measures
Boolean passwordIsValid = true;

// Loop through all the stored passwords we have for that user. We have a max of 10
for (String oldHashed: user.passwordHashHistory) {

    // Must re-hash every time using the same salt as the one stored in history
    // NOTE: SLLOOOWWWWW!
    String newHashed = Bcrypt.hashPw(rawPassword, oldHashed);

    // Now we can see if it's a match
    if (newHashed.compareTo(oldHashed) == 0) {
        // User is using one of the old passwords
        passwordIsValid = false;
    }
}
```

The above code works, but it can take 5-6 seconds on my workstation for one user to validate his password is changed. Can I do anything to mitigate this short of reducing the log rounds or beefing up the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BCrypt algorithm was designed precisely to be slow, with the cost factor you can determine how much time is needed to calculate a password hash. This "slowness" is the only way to thwart brute-force attacks.

If there was a way to speed up this process, an attacker would surely make use of it. So no there is no way to make short cuts here.

Comment: That's understandable. What I still don't understand is how to meet the password history requirement with a slow hash function, i.e., to see how others have solved this. For example if there's a breach and we need everyone to change their passwords, it would theoretically make the system unusable since all the resources are going into computing bcrypt hashes.

Comment: @Joe - I think the question is more, whether a history of 10 remembered passwords really makes sense. Facing users with such restriction, you often end up with weaker passwords, because users cannot remember tons of strong passwords. They can get very inventive ("password-1", "password-2", ...). If you really cannot avoid this requirement, keep in mind that a password change is a rare thing. In case of an emergency you could skip this restriction and check only the last password. In any case i would never reduce security by decreasing the cost factor in favor of such a requirement.

Comment: @Joe - If anyone offers such a system with checking the last 10 passwords, you can be sure that his system uses a weak hash algorithm (or the user has to wait).